# How do I get SQL table row number from assoc array with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, associative-array

```
$database = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM values ORDER BY value DESC";
$values = $database->query($sql);

while($row = $values->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row["value"];
}

$database->close();
```

PHP fetches the associative array from the SQL table values, then it loops through the array and echoes the 'value' column. How can I get it to echo the row number as well? I can't have a separate column with the row numbers in it because the rows are ordered the number stored in the 'value' column and regularly change about.

Thanks.

Comment: $values->num_rows is what you need

Comment: you realize that `VALUES` is reserved in mysql

Comment: Names are edited. @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: if your table doesn't have a `primary_key`, there is something really bad going on in your table schema.

Comment: You could toss a new variable in there and increment upon each loop of your `while`. Or you could add a column into your query like `SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, values.* FROM values ...` and then reference your new derived `row_number` column in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the simplest solution would likely be:

```
$database = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM values ORDER BY value DESC";
$values = $database->query($sql);

$cnt = 0;
while($row = $values->fetch_assoc()){
    $cnt ++;
    echo $row["value"] . $cnt;
}

$database->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have an "id" column in the table you can echo $row["id"], otherwise create a variable $i=0, increment its value by 1 on every iteration of the loop and echo $i